# Display list of data - one by one

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display the list of data:

```
<li ng-repeat="d in list_of_data">
    <div class="line">
       {{ d }}
    </div>
</li>
```

But I want to have a pause between the appearance each line of data, so I use such code:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.list_of_data = [];

    $scope.start = function() {
        var a = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten'];

        var addElement = function(i) {
            alert(i);
            $scope.list_of_data.push(a[i]);
            if (i < a.length - 1)
                setTimeout(function() { addElement(i+1); }, 1000);

        }

        addElement(0);                    
    };   
}
```

But when I launch the code I get all numbers (0..9) in alert window, but only one DIV ('one') in the page.  Why ?

Here is a [JSFidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/demas/bh9pvy04/3/)

Comment: ng-repeat is a complex directive that does multiple things. it creates a child scope for each element in the collection. in btw, it has a compile function & a linking function. i know, the linking function is meant for substituting collection element values inside html template string. but, does anyone know what does the compile function do?

Comment: well, is there any way to do my task using angular ?

Comment: the question is a very interesting one... i am happy, that it is raised...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that function passed as the first argument of `setTimeout` executed out of digest cycle and  view not updated. Better to use `$timeout` service of the `setTimeout` function:

By the way, for me looks better solution with applying limitTo filter and increment limit with $interval:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.list_of_data = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten'];

    $scope.limit = 0;

    $scope.start = function() {
      $interval(function() {
        $scope.limit += 1;
      }, 1000, $scope.list_of_data.length);
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <a href="#" ng-click="start()">press me</a> 
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="d in list_of_data|limitTo:limit">
        <div class="line">{{d}}</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `$timeout` or need to call `$scope.$digest()` at end of the `addElment`.

```
var addElement = function(i) {
        alert(i);
        $scope.list_of_data.push(a[i]);
        if (i < a.length - 1)
            setTimeout(function() { addElement(i+1); }, 1000);
         $scope.$digest();   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.list_of_data = [];

$scope.start = function() {
    var a = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten'];

    var addElement = function(i) {
        alert(i);
        $scope.list_of_data.push(a[i]);
        **$scope.$apply($scope.list_of_data);**
        if (i < a.length - 1)
            setTimeout(function() { addElement(i+1); }, 1000);

    }

    addElement(0);                    
};


}
```

Here is your solution: - http://jsfiddle.net/bh9pvy04/5/

$apply will ensure that all the models has been updated with the new values. This will will make the list updated and you will be able to see all the components in that list